# Interpolated string type can't be used to index record with the same type as key

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use an interpolated string type to index a `Record` type using a key that should match the key type of the record. However it does not seem to be working.

Here's a minimal example:

```
type TypeOfKey = `chart-${number}`|`text-${number}`;
// type TypeOfKey = string; // It works when KeyType is this type

interface ReportComponent {
    identifier: TypeOfKey;
}

interface Report {
    components: Record<TypeOfKey, ReportComponent>;
}

const component : ReportComponent = {
    identifier: 'text-2'
};

const report : Report = {
    components: {
        'text-2': component
    }
};


if (report.components[component.identifier] !== undefined) {  // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'TypeOfKey' can't be used to index type 'Record<TypeOfKey, ReportComponent>'
    // do something
}
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. As noted in the code, if I just use `string` as  `TypeOfKey` it works.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEHkBmBpCIoF4oAMDGAFgIYBOwAtACQDeAdgK4C2ARhCQL44A+OwEAHhRoMWbTgG4AUAHppUUJFjxkaDNgDOwEgEtaAc3FRZUAJLAoAdwD2JANbrLBCLSiq4i7Q+AFP8+JMldPhIkIjxoACUIMBtgAGErRhjaZ3NqSShMqG0AE1TtJG02AC4lSBV0KXYAoLZQ8KgomLIodKyoPETk1PVSqM6SHIAed0RUdAAaRujYhKSrFNpgAD4qgM7aTQ6uhdSoPpmyOe6lrFaMrNz8wpKoAHI+QXIAJjvJdilJDa2SQ-MD5rmbBtLKdeaLYC9c7tdoPAQUV6lMEnYAXTLVD4BQJIKAACl+gIAdMjdkt1ABtEkQwlXJYFIokAC6UAAhJhsPRaHlCikcgBKVqZYwAUQANhBGHttElRdo8NpgKKMMQHEQXHc1SA7n5FKw8ER6OpoAIwL91OptAsoFYcQpoHdRhUtR01Q8oKwoIaIDl5FZslyBDr7f0bMNHeMQFMmrMdhDlm92sYcn71IkIN5dHp3kA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bad news is that typescript 4.3 and lower do not support string template literals as index signatures. Your choices are `string` `number` or a union of specific strings, or specific numbers. A pattern is not supported.

The good news is that [typescript 4.4 will support this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4-beta/#symbol-template-signatures).

And your example works [without modification in the 4.4 beta](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEHkBmBpCIoF4oAMDGAFgIYBOwAtACQDeAdgK4C2ARhCQL44A+OwEAHhRoMWbTgG4AUAHppUUJFjxkaDNgDOwEgEtaAc3FRZUAJLAoAdwD2JANbrLBCLSiq4i7Q+AFP8+JMldPhIkIjxoACUIMBtgAGErRhjaZ3NqSShMqG0AE1TtJG02AC4lSBV0KXYAoLZQ8KgomLIodKyoPETk1PVSqM6SHIAed0RUdAAaRujYhKSrFNpgAD4qgM7aTQ6uhdSoPpmyOe6lrFaMrNz8wpKoAHI+QXIAJjvJdilJDa2SQ-MD5rmbBtLKdeaLYC9c7tdoPAQUV6lMEnYAXTLVD4BQJIKAACl+gIAdMjdkt1ABtEkQwlXJYFIokAC6UAAhJhsPRaHlCikcgBKaFZYw5KxQdSJCDeXR6d5AA).